# No surrond audio with my Logitech G430

Tags: usb, audio, headset, logitech-headset

Recently, I've had a problem with my Logitech G430 headphones. Sometimes the surround sound is turned off. This happened to me recently when I launched the OBS streaming software. I had solved the problem by updating my CM drivers and changing the USB port on my headset but the problem came back.

To make it more clear, I can't hear WhatsApp audios but also some sounds in Rocket League for example.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

I can only hear the L and R sounds on the picture below.

[image: Example]

Comment: To get surround sound, the input signal has to be encoded in surround sound, either natively or put through a stereo to surround processing algorithm.  Your headset only has 2 physical speakers.  It probably relies on a Logitech driver to get the surround effect.  Try configuring it in [Logitech Gaming Software for G430](https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360024695414--Downloads-G430-Surround-Sound-Gaming-Headset) rather than the generic Windows sound settings.

Comment: @Blaelph thank you for your advice, I solve this by uninstalling the Logitech G Hub software and by downloading another Logitech software. Now it works again :)

Comment: Awesome!  Glad you were able to resolve it.  I've had issues with Windows 10 updating drivers that don't work as well as the older ones, so if it happens again, you might need to repeat the driver uninstall/install process again.

Comment: @Blaelph Yes, I agree with you. Moreover, I was using Soundtrack by Twitch which a new tool made specifically for Twitch creators to feature licensed music within their live streams. When I launch it, the surround audio of my headset is again deactivated. I've uninstalled it. So for future readers of this post, it might be caused by Soundtrack by Twitch.